# Is there a way to simplify OpenCl kernels usage ?

Tags: opencl

To use OpenCL kernel the following is needed:

> 1. Put the kernel code in a string
> 2. call clCreateProgramWithSource
> 3. call clBuildProgram
> 4. call clCreateKernel
> 5. call clSetKernelArg (x number of arguments)
> 6. call clEnqueueNDRangeKernel

This need to be done for each kernel. Is there a way to do this repeating less code for each kernel?

Comment: Is there a utility toolkit for OpenCL? - similar to GLUT for writing OpenGL programs

Comment: You might be able to use SYCL

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to speed up the process. You need to go step by step as you listed.

But it is important to know why it is needed these steps, to understand how flexible the chain is.

- **clCreateProgramWithSource**: Allows to add different strings from different sources to generate the program. Some string might be static, but some might be downloaded from a server, or loaded from disk. It allows the CL code to be dynamic and updated over time.
- **clBuildProgram**: Builds the program for a given device. Maybe you have 8 devices, so you need to call this multiple times. Each device will produce a different binary code.
- **clCreateKernel**: Creates a kernel. But a kernel is an entry point in a binary. So it is possible you create multiple kernels from a program (for different functions). Also the same kernel might be created multiple times, since it holds the arguments. This is useful for having ready-to-be-launched instances with proper parameters.
- **clSetKernelArg**: Changes the parameters in the instance of the kernel. (it is stored there, so it can used multiple times in the future).
- **clEnqueueNDRangeKernel**: Launches it, configuring the size of the launch and the chain of dependencies with other operations.

So, even if you could have a way to just call "getKernelFromString()", the functionality will be very limited, and not very flexible.

Comment: Is there a utility toolkit for OpenCL?  - similar to GLUT for writing OpenGL programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can have look at wrapper libraries 
https://streamhpc.com/knowledge/for-developers/opencl-wrappers/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [SYCL](http://sycl.tech/). The building steps are performed offline, saving execution time by skipping the clCreateProgramWithSource. The argument setting is done automatically by the runtime, extracting the information from the user lambda

Answer (score 1):

There is also CLU: https://github.com/Computing-Language-Utility/CLU - see https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2012-siggraph-opencl-bof/OpenCL-CLU-and-Intel-SIGGRAPH_Aug12.pdf for more info. It is a very simple tool, but should make life a bit easier.